# Open TFS Query in Visual Studio from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a code that accesses a TFS, retrieves a query, modifies it (it sets the changed date to >= 'last time I executed it') and then I would like to display the results of the query in Visual Studio - as if I would have double clicked on one of my predefined queries in Team Explorer.

Remarks: I don't want to write my own UI to display the results. However I cannot go with predefined queries or modify a predefined query because VS does not support queries with time precision like `[System.ChangedDate] >= '2015-04-02T11:45:00.0000000'`. But it is possible to specify and execute such a query in code with `new Query(workitemstore, query, null, false)` where the last parameter indicates that I need time precision (and not date precision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as it seems (after talking to some TFS admins, browsing the web and experimenting around) time precision can be turned on (= date precision turned off) solely when executing a query by the means of the TFS API. I went "back" to exporting my query into Excel and fetching up-to-date data by using the Update button on the Team ribbon and then applying a filter on the changed date column.

Answer (score 1):

One option can be to store your query in a wiq (Work Item Query) file and then just open it. As VS created an associate of this type of file with itself opening it will automatically instantiate VS and run the query (if VS is already running then it will just open in a new window).

The wiq file is a very simple xml file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WorkItemQuery Version="1">
  <TeamFoundationServer>url of TFS server</TeamFoundationServer>
  <TeamProject>your project name</TeamProject>
  <Wiql>your query (e.g. SELECT ...)</Wiql>
</WorkItemQuery>
```

You can simply create a template of this file by saving an existing query and then just replace the time in the template with the whatever time you want.

Comment: This goes into to the right direction and I was quite enthusiastic about the solution, but was disappointed by Visual Studio - I end up getting the same messagebox saying that I cannot indicate a time when working with date precision (what VS does always). Is there a possibility to say DatePrecision = Disabled in the XML above?